# Include JS files based on current page

Tags: jsf, richfaces, facelets

I have the following on my main jsf wrapper page:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>
    <ui:insert name="pageTitle" /> 
  </title>

  <a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js" />
  <a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/base.js" />
  <a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/common.js" />
  <a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/inactivity.js" />
</head>
```

Now I have a new page on the site and it requires some js functions. So i have created a new js file, myNewJSFile.js

I only want it loaded if a user lands on this page so obviosuly I dont want to add it to my above list of files in the head. Additionally I'd rather not include it at the top of my new page.

What I want is one place where I can define what files to load based on the current page.

So somthing like this (Pseudo code):

main jsf wrapper:

```
<head>
  <jsIncludes>
</head>
```

jsIncludes file:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js" />
<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/base.js" />
<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/common.js" />
<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/inactivity.js" />

<if page == "myNewPage>
  <a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/myNewJsFile.js" />
<elfeif ...>
...
</if>
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a4j:loadScript` always places the javascript in the `<head>`, no matter where you use it, you have to do nothing. (the doc doesn't mention this for some strange reason)

So to answer your question: if you use `<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/myNewJsFile.js" />` in the page where you need it, the `<script style="text/javascript" src="..." />` will appear in the `<head>`.

Comment: If that is true, then that's the way to go. JSF 2.0 provides by the way the `<h:outputScript>` which also inserts it in the `<head>` regardless of where you declare it.

Comment: Yes, I tested that there and it certainly does put everything in the head using a4j:loadScript. I'll go with that solution. Thanks Adam & BalusC.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather add another `<ui:insert>` to the `<head>` of the main template.

```
<head>
    ...
    <ui:insert name="headContent" />
</head>
```

Then in the page template, just define the additional script to be inserted there.

```
<ui:composition template="main.xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://??? can't tell from top of head :)"
>
    <ui:define name="headContent">
        <a4j:loadScript src="resource:///bla/html/js/myNewJsFile.js" />
    </ui:define>

    ...
</ui:composition>
```